# UIButton not called when place on Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to add button on top of view, that are on top of self.view, that have navigation bar. Please take look at left part of navigation bar:

[image]

"Cross" button is placed upon second view (white-transparrent) that is placed above superview. For some reason, when i try to press "cross" block not called. But, when i move it to another position, that is not on navigation bar, it work (block called). How to make it call when it place when it suppose to be placed?

Here is some code:

```
UIButton *crossButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        [crossButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_hint"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [crossButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_hint"] forState:UIControlStateApplication];
        [_hole addSubview:crossButton];

    [crossButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {

        make.left.equalTo(_hole.mas_left).with.offset((sideMenuRect.size.width)*0.7);
        make.top.equalTo(_hole.mas_top).with.offset((sideMenuRect.origin.y)+ (sideMenuRect.size.height * 0.8));

    }];

    crossButton.rac_command = [[RACCommand alloc]initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {

        return [RACSignal empty];
    }];
```

Comment: what is _hole and where is it added ?

Comment: like that: self.hole = [JMHoledView new];
    self.hole.dimingColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.hole.alpha = 0.9;
    [self.tableView addSubview:self.hole];
    
   
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    [window addSubview:self.hole]; It is custom trasnparent UIView, you may google it if you want to.